How to copy folder but exclude files /folders with certain string?
I need to copy several folders to another destination on the same server but not any of the files or folder names that starts with 'mauris' , ex. maurisless , mauris_gt , etc. So any files or folders contains 'mauris' should not copied.   How can I achieve that ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

how does this relate to ask ubuntu?

you can use the rsync command with the --exclude option.
rsync -av --exclude='mauris*' /path/to/source/folder/ /path/to/destination/folder/

that would do the job.
